# How to compare the already saved value of node and updated value?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, hooks, updating

I want to programmatically compare a field value of a node in `hook_node_update()`. How can I get the already saved and the updated values?

Comment: why do you want to get it there? why don't want to get it instead before saving?
in your custom submit handler, before node getting saved you can get old and submitted value?

Comment: Actually i want to send email notification on change value of fields

Comment: Need more details. Where is the updated data coming from and do you have access to it. Existing data is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is using simple way, register custom submit handler then  before items saved compare submitted field value with  saved value.

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'contenttype_node_form') { // Replace contenttype
      array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'my_custom_submit_handler')
  }
}

function my_custom_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
   if(!empty($form_state['values']['nid'])){
   // Load the current node object
  $node = node_load($form_state['values']['nid']); 

  // Display the current node object's values
//  dsm($node);

  // Display the submitted values
  //dsm($form_state['values']);
if($form_state['values']['yourfield']['und'][0]['value'] != $node->yourfield['und'][0]['value']){
// do what you want here
  }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 7):

[`node_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7.x), which invokes `hook_node_update()`, contains the following code.

```
// Load the stored entity, if any.
if (!empty($node->nid) && !isset($node->original)) {
  $node->original = entity_load_unchanged('node', $node->nid);
}
```

So, every time a node is updated, `$node->original` will contain the node object before it is updated.

To get, for example, the value the *field_example* field had before the update, you use the following code.

```
$old_value = field_get_items('node', $node->original, 'field_example');
```

To get the updated value for the same field, you use the following code.

```
$new_value = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_example');
```

Comment: in Drupal 8 $node->original is also accessible in hook_node_update